# Redirect lots of system.out.println's to a .txt file

Tags: java, file-io, println, printstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print java output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695331/print-java-output-to-a-file)

In a Java program, I have a long method, (which I don't think is important to post since it's not vital to the question) that has a large number of println statements to print status updates to the console.

Instead of having these printout to the console, I'd like them to go into a txt file where I can store them and review them later.

Is there a simple way to redirect the output without manually going through each println statement?

If not, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can certainly redirect the standard output. Look at `System.setOut(PrintStream out)` in the [System class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). The PrintStream is one of your own that outputs to a file.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is a perfectly upvoteable answer :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I've reached my up-vote receiving limit, and regardless, I'm 100% sure that this question is a duplicate and in fact has been asked many many times, but I'm too lazy to look up for duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System class has a static method, `System.setOut(PrintStream out)`. All you have to do is create your own PrintStream that writes to a file, stuff it into this method and you're all set.

Better less fragile solution: Don't use System.out.printFoo(...) but instead just use a logger, and change the logging levels as it suits your purposes at that time.

Answer (score 11):

I have had to do this before, it isn't very neat and I hope you aren't doing it for a final piece of code, but I did:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("\file.txt");
PrintStream orig = System.out;
System.setOut(ps);
//TODO: stuff with System.out.println("some output");
System.setOut(orig);
ps.close();
```

Comment: it works thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

1. add extra parameter to the method `, PrintStream out`
2. search&replace `System.out` with `out` in your method.
3. done.
4. (call method with a PrintStream wrapped around a FileOutputStream)