# Is there a way to redirect the print statements in a Java program to required text files?

Tags: java, filestream

How to copy the contents of a print statement of a Java program to a text file using Print Stream?

Comment: You mean from inside the program or when you are running it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic : not clear with your question

Comment: You can redirect a program that writes to the default `System.out`  when you run it (for example, on Linux/Mac, `java MyProgram > file.txt`), or you can change the `System.out` inside the program itself. So which of those options do you want?

Comment: While running @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following code to do that from some time now. It works fine. There might be a better way.

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("\file.txt");
PrintStream orig = System.out;
System.setOut(ps);
//TODO: stuff with System.out.println("some output");
System.setOut(orig);
ps.close();
```

Comment: uhmm... that makes more sense than my answer, I think I misunderstood the question.... +1 and deleting my answer!!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552342/redirect-lots-of-system-out-printlns-to-a-txt-file] Here is the original answer. Credits to @iainmackay85. It has helped me a lot!

Comment: add it to your answer so anybody can flag you for plagiarism;)

Comment: Your coding works but  no content is copied to the file

Comment: It does work for me. Perhaps you can add your code to your question so that I can look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Consult this answer for better clarification [redirect to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("d:/output.txt")));
        System.out.println("StackOverflow");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @SANTHOSHB.E if it works then you can accept the answer :)

Comment: yes ,but the  answer by PuRak also working fine , is it possible to accept both the answers

Comment: @SANTHOSHB.E not possible to accept both the answers.. You should accept his answer.. Because his answer was posted earlier than my answer..